# Find intersection on a line with known angle and a line from known point with a specific conditions

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-geometry

Is there a solution to problem shown on a sketch? There is a known line trough fixed point **P1(0,0)** with known variable angle **α**. There is also a point **P3** with known variable coordinates **P3(T,H)**. I need to find either point **P11** or angle **β** so that distance from **P1** to **P11** is equal to distance from **P11** to **P12**. Point **P12** lies on vertical line at **x=C** which is known variable.
So known variables are: **α**, **T**, **C**, **L=T-C** and **H**

Need to find: either angle **β** or coordinate(s) of a point **P11** expressed as above known variables.

I have tried everything I know: intersections of lines, distance form point to point, circle-line intersections, but closest I can get is 3. degree equation which is not usable.

[image: Sketch]

Comment: not said in text, but on the figure you have another constraint: P11, P12 , P3 aligned. right ?

Comment: Actually geometric problem I came up on a job. I must inscribe arc between points P1 and P12 so that Lines P1-P11 and P11-P12 are its tangents.

Comment: Yes P11, P12 and P3 are aligned.

Comment: well, degree 3 is easily solvable ! similar to degree 2, just a little bit more involve.

Comment: @mark: could you please explain your original problem? It appears to me that in order to make both $\overline{P_1P_{11}}$ and $\overline{P_{11}P_{12}}$ tangents of a circle, they do not have to be of the same lengths. Do both points $P_{11}, P_{12}$ have to be on the circle? Does it have to be a circle at all? Or do you just want some "smooth" curve?

Comment: @nullThe original idea was to program a shape. Shape is formed as a curve and a line where user defines their parameters. Parameters i want user to control is curve width **C**, total width **T** (where line width is **L=T-C**), vertical position of shape endpoint **H**, and startpoint angle of a curve (tangent) **α**. Condition is that line part of a shape is tangent to curve part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $P_{11} = l. (sin(\alpha),cos(\alpha))$
- $\frac{Y_{12}-H}{C-T} = \frac{l.sin(\alpha)-H}{l.cos(\alpha)-T} \rightarrow Y_{12}=H+(C-T)\frac{l.sin(\alpha)-H}{l.cos(\alpha)-T}$
- $(l.sin(\alpha)-Y_{12})^2+(l.cos(\alpha)-C)^2=l^2$
  $\rightarrow -2.l.sin(\alpha)Y_{12} + Y_{12}^2 -2.l.cos(\alpha)C+C^2=0$

yep, this makes a degree 3 equation in $l$ to be solved (which is classically doable, [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)).

Comment: Yes, that is how I got equation. I hoped there might be simple solution.